# Flutter delayed animation shows no animation curve

Tags: flutter, dart

I have currently a problem with delayed animations. I use the FadeTransition widget to fade in the content of the page and fade out some Text, which is displayed at the beginning. 
It works, however the animation is very abrupt.

Edit: Never mind. The Interval values where > 1.0. The code below works now fine.

```
class _SinglePhotoState extends State<SinglePhoto> with TickerProviderStateMixin{

  AnimationController controller, controllerText;
  Animation<double> delayedAnimation, delayedText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 5), vsync: this);
    controllerText = AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 3), vsync: this);
    delayedText = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0).animate(
       CurvedAnimation(
          parent: controllerText,
          curve: Interval(0.25, 0.5, curve: Curves.easeIn)
       ));
    delayedAnimation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
       CurvedAnimation(
          parent: controller,
          curve: Interval(0.5, 1.0, curve: Curves.easeIn)
       ));

        controllerText.forward();
        controller.forward();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the animations also very abrupt in Profile or Release builds?

I notice that my animations are also very inconsistent and choppy in debug mode. 
But in Profile builds everything is fine.

Comment: I fixed it. The Interval value was bigger 1.0